# Webkit webBrowser engine visual basic 2010 component

Tags: visual-studio-2010, browser, webkit, components

Is there any way to import a webkit engine browser component to visual basic 2010 so i can use it in my project instead of the default IE?

Comment: interesting question!! You mean to use the parser? Maybe you can find "pieces" of webkit: parser/rendering engine... all are sepated features and if you don't need them all there might be a solution??

Comment: did you try installing google frame on ie?

Comment: Hmm sorry about the late response. Actually I was hoping for an easier approach. Maybe there is something I can download, put somewhere in the installation directory of visual basic and it will appear in the toolbar so i can drag and drop it in form and use it instead of the regular webbrowser component vb comes with.

Comment: i see. What about the google frame?

Comment: It seems promising. Nice workaround I'll definitely give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, simply use that http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/ 
I dont tried it, I always used the Gecko Engine in .NET, never had problems with it, it is more famous: http://www.geckofx.org/ but they just broke their website